# A persist insert all data from OneToMany ArrayCollection variable

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I have a bug when I try to persist a data, and I did not found help about someone having exactly the same problem....

I have two linked entities **score**(ManyToOne)/**player**(OneToMany) and when I persist the **score**, doctrine insert all the scores stored in the array collection $scores of the **player** corresponding to the score I want to store.
For information, I store each score of a round, so an user have more than one score (so the manyToOne/OneToMany relation).

I have a list of players with all their scores. I only want to insert the last one, like the others are already in the db. But for each solutions I tried, doctrine insert all the scores... even if I only put the last score in the player score.
Then, I delete the persist cascade on each entities, doctrine throw an exception about a link on entities...

Here is the Score entity

```
/**
 * Score
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="score")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\ScoreRepository")
 */
class Score
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Player", inversedBy="scores", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="player", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 * @var Player
 */
private $player;

/**
 * @var DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="played_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $playedAt;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="integer")
 */
private $value;
```

Here is the Player entity :

```
/**
 * Player
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="player")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\PlayerRepository")
 */
class Player extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $firstname;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $lastname;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="job", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $job;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Score", mappedBy="player", cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection|Score[]
 */
private $scores;
```

Here is now, my controller where I want to persist the score

```
$content = $request->getContent();
    $scoresParams = [];
    if (!empty($content))
    {
        $scoresParams = json_decode($content, true); // 2nd param to get as array
    }
    $players = array();

    $transformer = $this->get('app.transformer.score');
    foreach($scoresParams as $k=>$v) {
        $players[] = $transformer->reverseTransform($v);
    }
    foreach($players as $k=>$p) {
        $index = count($p->getScores()) - 1;
        $s = $p->getScores()[$index];
        $p->setScores(array($s));
        $this->get('app.repository.score')->persist($s);
    }
```

I setted the player score with just the score I want to save... Because, like i have a persist on cascad, and all the others scores of the users are not retrieve from doctrine, hit will try to insert them...
So, for the first player, ok, but for the second, $s has already an ID when i persist it, and it persist all the data of the player (not only the last one).

The transformer is a bundle (League\Fractal\Transformer) which creates an array of players from a array of data

```
public function reverseTransform(array $data)
{
    $this->checkRequiredFields($data);

    $player = $this->playerRepository->find($data[self::KEY_ID]);

    if (!$player) {
        throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
    }

    $scoresRaw = $data[self::KEY_ENC_SCORES];
    $scores = array();

    foreach($scoresRaw as $k => $s) {
        $score = new Score($player);
        if($s[self::KEY_ENC_SCORE_ID] != 0) {
            $score->setId($s[self::KEY_ENC_SCORE_ID]);
        }
        $score->setPlayedAt( ( new \DateTime() )->setTimestamp( $s[self::KEY_ENC_SCORE_DATE] ) );
        $score->setValue($s[self::KEY_ENC_SCORE_VALUE]);
        $scores[] = $score;
    }

    $player->setScores($scores);

    return $player;
}
```

Can you see what's wrong here ?

---

Here is the solution
-> controller

```
        $content = $request->getContent();
    $scoresParams = [];
    if (!empty($content))
    {
        $scoresParams = json_decode($content, true); // 2nd param to get as array
    }
    $players = array();

    $transformer = $this->get('app.transformer.score');
    // For each players
    foreach($scoresParams as $i=>$player) {
        $scores = $player['scores'];
        foreach($scores as $j=>$s) {
            $score = $transformer->reverseTransform($s['data']);
            $this->get('app.repository.score')->merge($score);
        }
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse(array('data' => ''));
    $response->setStatusCode(201);

    return $response;
```

And the function that reverse the score array to an object

```
    $player = $this->playerRepository->find($data[self::KEY_USER]);

    if (!$player) {
        throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
    }

    $score = new Score($player);
    if($data[self::KEY_ID] != 0) {
        $score->setId($data[self::KEY_ID]);
    }
    $score->setPlayedAt( ( new \DateTime() )->setTimestamp( $data[self::KEY_DATE] ) );
    $score->setValue($data[self::KEY_VALUE]);

    return $score;
```

Comment: I would suggest you to name better your variables, it's kinda hard to get in the code ^^ `$scores = $player['scores'];` -> `$playerScores`. In your foreachs: `foreach($scoresParams as $scoreParam)` (you don't use your key). Don't take it personally, I really think you would gain a lot of time this way when you will come back on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your entity comes from a json, it is not linked to the entity manager.

I think you should use `merge()` method to link it.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities

```
    $score->setValue($s[self::KEY_ENC_SCORE_VALUE]);
    $this->get('app.repository.score')->merge($score);
    $scores[] = $score;
}
$player->setScores($scores);
```

Comment: I already tried this in the controller (instead of the persist), and this has the same result... 
Doctrine store the new score and all the score of the player.
That's what I was thinking, but removing all the scores of an user and only put the last one I want, does not change... It seems that Doctrine retrieve all the scores and try to re-insert them...

Comment: Ok now, it's good with your solution.
I had to rewrite the source code, with a point of view more focused on the score and not the user.
I will update my question to put the solution